# How to display a list in c++

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to print a list in C++.
My code is as follows:

```
void MovieFunctions::printMovieList(list<Movie> movies)
{
    for (Movie m: movies)
    {
        cout << m << endl;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error for the `cout << m << endl` line:

> cannot convert 'm' (type 'Movie') to type 'const unsigned char*'

What's going wrong?

Comment: "I am getting an errow for the "cout << m << endl" line?"  You know we can't guess the error, right?

Comment: Show your code (don't link to it). And give us the full error message.

Comment: Sean, you should tell which error you are getting...

Comment: My error message is as follows 'cannot convert 'm' (type 'Movie') to type 'const unsigned char*'

Comment: OT: `for (Movie m: movies)` creates a copy of each Movie. Use `for (const Movie& m: movies)` or `for (const auto& m: movies)`

Comment: _How to display a list in c++_ there is no error that's associated with a list.

Comment: OT: `printMovieList(list<Movie> movies)`copies the entire list. use `printMovieList(const list<Movie>& movies)`

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement the `operator<<()` ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)) for this purpose.